# How to delete a pattern from String?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, string-manipulation

Having a string like :

```
"{Aaaa -> a, Bbbb- > b, Cccc -> , Ddddd -> c, Eeeee -> , Fffff -> e}"
```

I want to delete the parts that contain `"a word" + "-> ,"` and replace them just with `","` to have result like

```
"{Aaaa -> a, Bbbb- > b, Ddddd -> c, Fffff -> e}"
```

So that I can bring this `ToExpression[]`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`StringCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringCases.html).

```
str = "{Aaaa -> a, Bbbb -> b, Cccc -> , Ddddd -> c, Eeeee -> , Fffff -> e}";
ToExpression@StringCases[str, WordCharacter .. ~~ " -> " ~~ WordCharacter ..]
```

> `{Aaaa -> a, Bbbb -> b, Ddddd -> c, Fffff -> e}`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a combination of `StringSplit`, `SyntaxQ` and `Pick`:

```
str = "{Aaaa -> a, Bbbb- > b, Cccc -> , Ddddd -> c, Eeeee -> , Fffff ->  e}";

str2 = Pick[#, SyntaxQ /@ #] &@StringSplit[str, "," | "{" | "}"]
(* {"Aaaa -> a", " Ddddd -> c", " Fffff -> e"} *)

ToExpression@str2
(* {Aaaa -> a, Ddddd -> c, Fffff -> e} *)
```

Comment: This is also a nice solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Or the `StringReplace` version:

```
In[3]:= StringReplace[str, WordCharacter .. ~~ " -> ," -> ""]
Out[3]= "{Aaaa -> a, Bbbb -> b,  Ddddd -> c,  Fffff -> e}"

In[4]:= ToExpression@%
Out[4]= {Aaaa -> a, Bbbb -> b, Ddddd -> c, Fffff -> e}
```